# State space of a pendulum as $S^{1} \times \Bbb{R}$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

I was reading about the State space of a Dynamical System from [Scholarpedia article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/State_space), I understood that a state space is a set of all possible sets of the Dynamical system.

But I was not able to understand how in the case of a pendulum where the degrees of freedom is 2 comprising of angle and velocity, then how does it represent $S^{1} \times \Bbb{R}$ like why a "cross" between them but I can visualize that $S^{1} \times \Bbb{R}$ is a cylinder.

Comment: The values your two-dimensional state can take belong to the Cartesian product of $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are pairs of points. The angle parametrizes $S^1$, and the velocity is taken as a scalar in $\mathbb R$. So the tuple is $(\theta,v) \in S^1 \times \mathbb R$.

Comment: Let me know if this is what you are looking for, it's actually a bit difficult for me to see the confusion.

Comment: Yes, that is it, I was a bit late identifying $(\theta , v)$ with $S^{1} \times \Bbb{R}$!

Comment: ah okay. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

The angle can be represented by some point on a circle, which is $S^1$. The velocity is some real number, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$. So, the whole system is represented by a pair $(\theta, v)$ where $\theta \in S^1$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}$, and hence is represented by the cross $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$.